# Textfile to class to Data Dictionary

Tags: c#, arrays, object, dictionary, data-structures

I'm trying to make a textfile that goes into a class and stores the object into a data dictionary and then create a GUI that allows me  to add, edit and remove etc.

My text file is in the following syntax:

*Country, GDP growth, Inflation, Trade Balance, HDI Ranking, Main Trade Partners*

Examples:

- USA,1.8,2,-3.1,4,[Canada;UK;Brazil]
- Canada,1.9,2.2,-2,6,[USA;China]

Anyway before I create the GUI, I am trying make it work in the console first. The Countries come up in the console but using the step into in the debugger, my object array and my data dictionary (if I have created the data dictionary correctly) seem to be storing but though when it goes on to the next country it overwrites the previous one. How can I make it so that all countries get stored instead of just the one. If that makes sense any help will be greatly appreciated.

My code:

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        const int MAX_LINES_FILE = 50000;
        string[] AllLines = new string[MAX_LINES_FILE];
        int i = 0;
        //reads from bin/DEBUG subdirectory of project directory
        AllLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jack\Documents\countries.csv");
        country[] newCountry = new country[30];

        foreach (string line in AllLines)
        {
            if (line.StartsWith("Country")) //found first line - headers
            {
                headers = line.Split(',');
            }
            else
            {
               string[] columns = line.Split(',');
                      newCountry[i] = new country();
                 newCountry[i].Country=(columns[0]);
                 newCountry[i].GDP=(columns[1]);
                 newCountry[i].Inflation=(columns[2]);
                 newCountry[i].TB =(columns[3]);
                 newCountry[i].HDI =(columns[4]);
                 newCountry[i].TP = (columns[5]);


                Dictionary<object, string> CountryList = new Dictionary<object, string>();
                CountryList.Add(newCountry[i].Country, newCountry[i].GDP + "," + newCountry[i].Inflation + "," + newCountry[i].TB + "," + newCountry[i].HDI + "," + newCountry[i].TP);
                i++;

               foreach (KeyValuePair<object, string> country in CountryList)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Country = {0}, GDP = {1}",
                        country.Key, country.Value);
                }

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    public static string[] headers { get; set; }
}


public class country
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string GDP { get; set; }
    public string Inflation { get; set; }
    public string TB { get; set; }
    public string HDI { get; set; }
    public string TP { get; set; }

}
```

}

EDIT: Moved the CountryList as suggested still getting the same issue that the countryList count is staying on 1.

I have put it in a method in the country class.

```
        public static void addD(country a)
    {
        Dictionary<object, string> CountryList = new Dictionary<object, string>();
        CountryList.Add(a.Country, a.GDP);


        foreach (KeyValuePair<object, string> country in CountryList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Country = {0}, GDP = {1}", country.Key, country.Value);
        }
    }
```

and calling it from here:

```
            newCountry[i].TB =(columns[3]);
         newCountry[i].HDI =(columns[4]);
         newCountry[i].TP = (columns[5]);
         country.addD(newCountry[i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, i have cleaned it up and added comments as it was very hard to work with.

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Initalize the loop iterator
        int i = 0;

        // Initalize a list of country data
        country[] newCountry = new country[30];

        // Initialize a list of countries
        Dictionary<object, string> countryList = new Dictionary<object, string>();

        // Read all the lines from the file
        string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Jack\Documents\countries.csv");

        // For each line in the file
        foreach (string line in fileLines)
        {
            // Check if the line is a header
            if (line.StartsWith("Country"))
            {
                headers = line.Split(',');
            }
            else
            {
                // Split the text data
                string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                // Initalize a new country
                newCountry[i] = new country
                {
                    Country = columns[0],
                    GDP = columns[1],
                    Inflation = columns[2],
                    TB = columns[3],
                    HDI = columns[4],
                    TP = columns[5]
                };

                countryList.Add(newCountry[i].Country, string.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4}", newCountry[i].GDP, newCountry[i].Inflation, newCountry[i].TB, newCountry[i].HDI, newCountry[i].TP));
                i++;
            }
        }

        // The process is done show the data
        foreach (KeyValuePair<object, string> country in countryList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Country = {0}, GDP = {1}", country.Key, country.Value);
        }

        // Wait for the user key
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static string[] headers { get; set; }

    public class country
    {
        public string Country { get; set; }
        public string GDP { get; set; }
        public string Inflation { get; set; }
        public string TB { get; set; }
        public string HDI { get; set; }
        public string TP { get; set; }

    }
```

Further update why even use the country collection? Below is a better approach

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // Initalize a list of country data
    List<country> countryList = new List<country>();

    // Read all the lines from the file
    string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"countries.csv");

    // For each line in the file
    foreach (string line in fileLines)
    {
        // Check if the line is a header
        if (line.StartsWith("Country"))
        {
            headers = line.Split(',');
        }
        else
        {
            // Split the text data
            string[] columns = line.Split(',');

            // Initalize a new country
            country fileCountry = new country
            {
                Country = columns[0],
                GDP = columns[1],
                Inflation = columns[2],
                TB = columns[3],
                HDI = columns[4],
                TP = columns[5]
            };

            countryList.Add(fileCountry);
        }
    }

    // The process is done show the data
    foreach (country country in countryList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Country = {0}, GDP = {1}", country.Country, country.GDP);
    }

    // Wait for the user key
    Console.ReadKey();
}

public static string[] headers { get; set; }

public class country
{
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string GDP { get; set; }
    public string Inflation { get; set; }
    public string TB { get; set; }
    public string HDI { get; set; }
    public string TP { get; set; }

}
```

Second update as per the question, listbox is a great way to start working win UI controls i have added the example below that works. Add a button called button1 and a listbox control called

```
// List holding all the country data
        private List<country> countryList;

        /// <summary>
        /// Handle the button click
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender">See MSDN</param>
        /// <param name="e">See MSDN</param>
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Initalize a list of country data
            this.countryList = new List<country>();

            // Set the display text to the display property of the country class
            this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "Display";

            // Set the value of the list box item to the current country
            this.listBox1.ValueMember = "Country";

            // Populate the data
            this.PopulateData();

            // Set the list box datasource
            this.listBox1.DataSource = this.countryList;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets the country data from the csv file
        /// </summary>
        private void PopulateData()
        {
            // Read all the lines from the file
            string[] fileLines = File.ReadAllLines(@"countries.csv");

            // For each line in the file
            foreach (string line in fileLines)
            {
                // Check if the line is a header
                if (line.StartsWith("Country"))
                {
                    headers = line.Split(',');
                }
                else
                {
                    // Split the text data
                    string[] columns = line.Split(',');

                    // Initalize a new country
                    country fileCountry = new country
                    {
                        Country = columns[0],
                        GDP = columns[1],
                        Inflation = columns[2],
                        TB = columns[3],
                        HDI = columns[4],
                        TP = columns[5]
                    };

                    this.countryList.Add(fileCountry);
                }
            }

            // The process is done show the data
            foreach (country country in this.countryList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(country.Display);
            }
        }

        public static string[] headers { get; set; }

        public class country
        {
            public string Country { get; set; }
            public string GDP { get; set; }
            public string Inflation { get; set; }
            public string TB { get; set; }
            public string HDI { get; set; }
            public string TP { get; set; }

            /// <summary>
            /// Formats the display string for the country 
            /// </summary>
            public string Display
            {
                get
                {
                    return string.Format("Country = {0}, GDP = {1}", this.Country, this.GDP);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Awesome! You're a saint. I think i have to use the Country selection but ill keep the other one in mind for future reference. 
Quick question before I inevitably get stuck again. I'm going to move this into a simple GUI now. 
Do you think it would be best to move the output into a listbox? 
 If so how would i go about adding a dictionary or a list(like your other suggestion) to a listbox? or would you suggest something else?

Comment: @MysteryMan113 I have updated my answer to include code for the listbox, if this has answered your question please mark as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You're declaring `CountryList` in the `foreach` block, so it loses scope at the end of each iteration, and you recreate it from scratch on the next iteration. You need to declare it either outside the `foreach` block or as a member of the class.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, moved the CountryList  from the foreach block to its own method in the country class but the countrylist count is still staying at 1

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more on what you mean when you say you moved it to its own method in the country class? What does the method do? How do you call it?

Comment: Dictionary<object, string> CountryList = new Dictionary<object, string>();
This code will create a new country list and clear any records you already have. This needs to be done once at the beginning of the process not every time you add a country.